# How can I make an if statement in a for-loop only occur for the first occurence after searching through elements in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, 2d

For example here is my code and attempt so far:

```
public void probeClicked(){

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons[0].length; j++) {

            if (counts[i][j]==MINE){
                buttons[i][j].setText("M");
                buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Probe clicked! 1 Mine has been revealed.");
                break;


            }
            else{

                continue;
            }

} }
```

I want to make it so that, as soon as it finds ONE mine, it breaks out of the loop and the method is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `break`, which will break out of the inner for loop, simply use a `return`.

```
public void probeClicked(){

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < buttons[0].length; j++) {

        if (counts[i][j]==MINE){
            buttons[i][j].setText("M");
            buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Probe clicked! 1 Mine has been revealed.");
            return;


        }
        else{

            continue;
        }
} }
```

Comment: Thank you, this did fix it a bit. My next issue now is that it only works on the first time that I even find a probe for some reason. If I find a probe again, mines are no longer detected despite the message in the if statement being displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your new problem. Whenever you enter the if statement the first (and only) time, the execution will leave this method. Isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Use return instead of break if you want the method to end. If you want it to continue after the outer loop, you could do like this:

```
outer:
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < buttons[0].length; j++) {
```

And in the if:

```
break outer;
```